# PHP variable in href in PHP

Tags: php, variables, href

I'm struggling with the syntax of this:

```
echo '<strong><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'data_sheet', true );?>" target="_blank">Datasheet</a></strong>';
```

The central PHP element gets a URL from a WooCommerce custom field (I know this works ok on its own). That needs to be turned into a viable link opening a new page, and the whole sits in a PHP wrapper on the page.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you get at the moment when that code runs?

Answer (score 2):

Try this hopefully, it will work.

```
echo '<strong><a href="' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'data_sheet', true ) . '" target="_blank">Datasheet</a></strong>';
```

Comment: @SteveBower Glad to help ;) please marked tick the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding more to / changing the href

something like this might work

```
echo '<strong><a href="data_sheet.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'" target="_blank">Datasheet</a></strong>';
```

You'll have to adjust a little bit, but should do the trick

Comment: This isn't going to work. You're already in PHP mode, so the string should be concated. You can't echo inside echo

Comment: You are right, I just edited the answer to remove the PHP tags

Comment: Slightly incorrect still, I corrected it for you. This will print correctly and shouldn't throw syntax errors